# c# - automatic opacity change in windows for app

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

I try to make my windows form app to change opacity from 1 to 0 (invisible form), and then back from 0 opacity to 1 (normal, visible form) when i press the button.

Every single opacity changing step is connected with timer. It make opacity change 
(-/+0,10) in every timer1_tick.

I start with Opacity = 1 (100%)

Now i have something like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double OpacityStep; 

    public Form1()
    {
        OpacityStep = 0.10; 
        InitializeComponent();
        updateButton1(); 
        updateButton2();
    }

    private void updateButton1() 
    {
        if (Opacity < 1.00) button1.Enabled = true; 
        else 
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void updateButton2()
    {
        if (Opacity > 0.0) button2.Enabled = true;
        else 
        {
            button1.Focus(); 
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double NewOpacity = Opacity + OpacityStep; 
        if (NewOpacity > 1.0) Opacity = 1.0; 
        else Opacity = NewOpacity;
        updateButton2(); 
        updateButton1();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double NewOpacity = Opacity - OpacityStep;

        if (NewOpacity < 0.0) Opacity = 0.0; 
        else Opacity = NewOpacity;
        updateButton1();
        updateButton2();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // app start
    {
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        button2_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

This code make my app invisible, but how make it back to visible (opacity = 1) ? ? ?

Comment: Not trying to be critical, but this is a really messy way of doing things... Any particular reason you are calling `Click` events for every method?

Comment: I just start programming, this is one of my first app, so i do what i can, not what is the best :>.

Comment: Then perhaps you should provide a more detailed explanation of what you _are really trying to accomplish_.  You'll get _much_ better answers.

Comment: Again, i'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  But if the code you posted works to make your form invisible.  Then reverse the process to make it visible again.  It's hard to follow the flow of your program, so hard to write an answer with actual code examples.

Answer (score 1):

"I try to make my windows form app to change opacity from 1 to 0 (invisible form), and then back from 0 opacity to 1 (normal, visible form) when i press the button."

Sounds pretty clear to me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    double OpacityStep = 0; 

    public Form1() 
    {            
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Interval = 100;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        this.Opacity = 1;
        OpacityStep = -0.10;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double NewOpacity = Opacity + OpacityStep;
        if (NewOpacity <= 0)
        {
            NewOpacity = 0;
            OpacityStep = 0.10;
        }
        else if(NewOpacity >= 1 && OpacityStep  > 0)
        {
            NewOpacity = 1.0;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        this.Opacity = NewOpacity;
    }

}
```

EDIT: "If i need to loop this ( opacity from 1 to 0 and back from 0 to 1, in loop), what should i change in this code ?"

With a for loop:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;

        // fade out:
        this.Opacity = 1.0;
        for (double opacity = 1.0; opacity >= 0.0; opacity = opacity - .1)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.Opacity = opacity;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        // fade in:
        this.Opacity = 0.0;
        for (double opacity = 0.0; opacity <= 1.0; opacity = opacity + .1)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.Opacity = opacity;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        this.Opacity = 1.0;

        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thx so much. I have one more question. If i need to loop this ( opacity from 1 to 0 and back from 0 to 1, in loop), what should i change in this code ?

Comment: If you want to use a loop then get rid of the timer...see added snippet above.